# Can ASP MVC automatically bind to a collection property in my EF4.1 entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would have thought this is a fairly common issue so hopefully easy to solve.

I have a basic user class like:

```
public class User
{
        public User()
        {
            SecurityGroups = new HashSet<SecurityGroup>();
        }

        public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
        public int TeamId {get;set;}

        public virtual ICollection<SecurityGroup> SecurityGroups { get; set; }
}
```

I am then creating a new instance via an ASP MVC app. The post data being returned is something like

```
"TeamId=2&SecurityGroups=1&SecurityGroups=5"
```

with a controller action like

```
public ActionResult(User user)
{
throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Based on this the MVC binder is populating the TeamId property fine, however (understandably) it doesn't know how to populate SecurityGroups.

What I am wondering is whether it is possible to have a 'primitive collection' in a manner similar to TeamId which the default binder could automatically populate? e.g.

```
public ICollection<int>SecurityGroupIds {get;set;}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have:

```
public ICollection<int> SecurityGroupIds { get;set; }
```

you could populate it like this:

```
TeamId=2&SecurityGroupIds=1&SecurityGroupIds=2&SecurityGroupIds=3
```

Or you could also populate complex collection objects:

```
TeamId=2
SecurityGroups[0].SomeProperty=value1
SecurityGroups[1].SomeProperty=value2
...
```

Take a look at the [following article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) to learn more about the wire format that the default model binder expects for collections and dictionaries.